# A socket operation encountered a dead network

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, compact-framework

My WinCE device (C#, CF 3.5) communicates with SERVER through socket.

When it works for more than 12hs it disconnect and this `Exception` occurs: `A socket operation encountered a dead network`.

For what I have read maybe the public IP change. But in my code I reconnect to the new IP so I don't know why this exception is thrown.

Comment: Which call exactly throughs this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a mobile device I'd say it's the device's IP address that changes.

And even more: The network provider might shutdown and restart the whole network connecting the device every 12hs.

In case of receiving `WSAENETDOWN` you should restart the whole IP client part of your application.

Comment: Thanks @alk, I solved it by restarting the GPRS connection before 12hs.

Answer (score 0):

The Server should have a **static** IP address. If it has a **dynamic** IP address, you could be running into this problem whenever a new IP address is assigned to your Server.

If this is the case, then you could/should write your Application to catch this one specific type of Exception (`SocketException`, maybe?), handle that Exception (perhaps a MessageBox letting the User know what's going on), and have your code to re-enter the routine using the new Server ID address.

You may need to re-initialize your socket connections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am already doing that: Every time the connection fails I re-initialize the socket and I connect to the Server finding out which is my IP through the DNS name. In my device I am connecting through GPRS, could it be this IP which is generating the problem? I made another try and again it disconnect at exactly 12 hours