# Windows phone a socket operation encountered a dead network

Tags: windows-phone-7, networking, windows-phone-8

I am trying to get the IP address of networks like **Wi-Fi,Data Network**. I use the following **class** to find the IP.

```
public class MyIPAddress
{
    Action<IPAddress> FoundCallback;
    UdpAnySourceMulticastClient MulticastSocket;
    const int PortNumber = 50000;       // pick a number, any number
    string MulticastMessage = "FIND-MY-IP-PLEASE" + new Random().Next().ToString();

    public void Find(Action<IPAddress> callback)
    {
        FoundCallback = callback;

        MulticastSocket = new UdpAnySourceMulticastClient(IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.250"), PortNumber);
        MulticastSocket.BeginJoinGroup((result) =>
        {
            try
            {
                MulticastSocket.EndJoinGroup(result);
                GroupJoined(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //  Debug.WriteLine("EndjoinGroup exception {0}", ex.Message);
                // This can happen eg when wifi is off
                FoundCallback(null);
            }
        },
            null);
    }

    void callback_send(IAsyncResult result)
    {
    }

    byte[] MulticastData;
    bool keepsearching;

    void GroupJoined(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        MulticastData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MulticastMessage);
        keepsearching = true;
        MulticastSocket.BeginSendToGroup(MulticastData, 0, MulticastData.Length, callback_send, null);

        while (keepsearching)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[MulticastData.Length];
                MulticastSocket.BeginReceiveFromGroup(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, DoneReceiveFromGroup, buffer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Debug.WriteLine("Stopped Group read due to " + ex.Message);
                keepsearching = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void DoneReceiveFromGroup(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        string str = "";
        IPEndPoint where;
        int responselength = MulticastSocket.EndReceiveFromGroup(result, out where);
        byte[] buffer = result.AsyncState as byte[];
        if (responselength == MulticastData.Length && buffer.SequenceEqual(MulticastData))
        {
            str = where.Address.ToString();
            keepsearching = false;
            FoundCallback(where.Address);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(str);

    }
}
```

I was successful to find out the IP address of connected **Wi-Fi**. I turn off Wi-Fi and turn on the **Data Connection**. I am not able to get the IP address of connected network. I got the error ** a socket operation encountered a dead network**.   I have also refer this question [A socket operation encountered a dead network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512555/a-socket-operation-encountered-a-dead-network). How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

*Question is a bit old, but answer may be useful for someone:*

You get this error, because your **MyIPAddress** class can only find a **local IP** (the address inside your internal WiFi network, behind router). To get an **external IP** address you should call an external server that will tell you your IP (eg. whatismyip.com).